# Multiple If Conditions Using String isEqualTo

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, if-statement, nsstring

Can anyone tell me what is wrong with the below?

```
if ( [isFormInputIncomplete   isEqualToString:@"1"] ||
     [isUserNameTaken         isEqualToString:@"1"] ||
     [isUserNameFormatInvalid isEqualToString:@"1"] ||
     [isPasswordInvalid       isEqualToString:@"1"] ||
     [isEmailInvalid          isEqualToString:@"1"] ) {
```

The error it gives me is:

```
-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x967a570

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber isEqualToString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x967a570'
```

** Edit July 20, 2013: I was returning a JSON from a PHP script that was being shared by both the Android and iOS versions of a mobile app. Java is flexible in that it was able to take in a number and treat it as a string. Objective-C on the other hand was not as forgiving which is why I came to this problem described above.

Comment: It means your variables are `NSNumber`s, not `NSString`s.  Fix that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One or all of the objects is a NSNumber and does not know how the handle the `isEqualToString:` message.

Because of their names I'd guess all are NSNumbers with boolean values

```
if ( [isFormInputIncomplete   isEqualToNumber:@YES] ||
     [isUserNameTaken         isEqualToNumber:@YES] ||
     [isUserNameFormatInvalid isEqualToNumber:@YES] ||
     [isPasswordInvalid       isEqualToNumber:@YES] ||
     [isEmailInvalid          isEqualToNumber:@YES] )
```

or

```
if ( [isFormInputIncomplete  boolValue] == YES ||
     //…)
```

to check, if a object is of a certain kind (class or subclass) you can use `isObjectOfKind:`

```
if([isFormInputIncomplete isKindOfClass: [NSNumber class]])
```

Comment: Agree with you and GB.  I might go with '[isFoo boolValue] == YES' for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like one of your values is an NSNumber rather than an NSString.  I can't tell which one.  When you find it, you'll want to use:

```
[isNumberValue isEqualToNumber:@1]
```